# Find the MIN/MAX/SUM from a Text File

Tags: java, arrays, sum, max, min

Input Text File:

> Min: 1,2,3,5,6
>
> Max: 1,2,3,5,6
>
> Avg: 1,2,3,5,6

Get the MIN/MAX and SUM from the list of numbers in the text file.

```
package net.codejava;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Formatter;

public class MyFile {
       public static int[] toIntArray(String input, String delimiter) {

            return  Arrays.stream(input.split(delimiter)).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //Declare Variables
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        double avg = 0.0;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String[] numArray = new String[30];
        int[] maxArray;
        int[] minArray;
        int[] sumArray;

        try {
            //Read the text file ('input.txt')
            String myFile = "input.txt";
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(myFile));    
            while(input.hasNext()) {
                input.next();
                numArray[count] = input.next();
                count++;
                }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");  
        }

        minArray = toIntArray(numArray[0],",");
        maxArray = toIntArray(numArray[1],",");
        sumArray = toIntArray(numArray[2],",");
        
        System.out.println(" Min Value " + Arrays.stream(minArray).min().getAsInt());
        System.out.println(" Max Value " + Arrays.stream(maxArray).max().getAsInt());
        System.out.println(" Sum Value " + Arrays.stream(sumArray).sum());
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

> The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 1
>
> The min of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 6
>
> The avg of [1, 2, 3, 5, 6] is 3.4

Current Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)

    at net.codejava.MyFile.main(MyFile.java:32)
```

Comment: if the file has non int value, the input.hasNextInt() return false and in this case the while loop ends

Comment: @b1ack_char1ie  - Could you check the latest solution please and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one of the simplest way of solving this using Arrays.stream method is below,

File Format :

```
Min:1,2,3,5,6
Max:1,2,7,5,6
Avg:1,2,3,5,6
```

Java code :

```
package org.personal.TestProject;


import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;


public final class MinMaxAvg {


    public static int[] toIntArray(String input, String delimiter) {

        return  Arrays.stream(input.split(delimiter))
                .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                .toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
//Declare Variables
        int min ;
        int max ;
        double avg ;
        int sum;
        int count = 0;
        String[] numArray = new String[3];
        int[] maxArray;
        int[] minArray;
        int[] sumArray;

//Read the text file ('input.txt')

            String fileName = "input.txt";
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));

//Read the numbers. Get count.
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            numArray[count] = input.next();
            count++;
        }

// Convert the comma seperated string to Int array after removing Min:, Max: and Avg: pattern from the string

        minArray = toIntArray(numArray[0].replaceAll("Min:",""),",");
        maxArray = toIntArray(numArray[1].replaceAll("Max:",""),",");
        sumArray = toIntArray(numArray[2].replaceAll("Avg:",""),",");

// Use arrays.stream to find min,max,sum and average. Sum and average is generated for last line

        min = Arrays.stream(minArray).min().getAsInt();
        max = Arrays.stream(maxArray).max().getAsInt();
        sum = Arrays.stream(sumArray).sum();
        avg = Arrays.stream(sumArray).average().getAsDouble();

        System.out.println(" Min Value     " + min);
        System.out.println(" Max Value     " + max);
        System.out.println(" Sum Value     " + sum);
        System.out.println(" Average Value " + avg);


    }
}
```

Output is below,

```
 Min Value     1
 Max Value     7
 Sum Value     17
 Average Value 3.4
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, it might be simple to you but not to me at this moment. I'm doing this at a beginner level approach. Read Text File, Get Count, Get Min, Get Max, Get Avg.

Comment: If it work,please mark/vote otherwise update the question with the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: I implemented your code but ran into a few output errors. I've updated my post.

Comment: You seems to have space in the beginning of line in the file, remove the blank space and run the code again.i.e. before  "Min:" there is a space.

Comment: I had a look and can confirm no whitespace before min.

Comment: @B1ackChar1ie - Could you check the modified code.Not sure what was the issue in the first version, it didn't work to me when i reloaded the code to the IDE but worked in the first place. This should work.

Comment: Thanks, this code executes as it should. Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
package MyFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MinMaxAvg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create File object
        try {
            File fileName = new File("input.txt");
            File output = new File("output.txt");
            
            //Create Scanner to read file
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileName);
            
            //Output the file line by line
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
            
            //Read each line of file using Scanner class
            while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scnr.nextLine();

                // split the line and place them in an array.
                int[] numList = splitString(line);
                                
                if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("min")) {
                    getMin(numList, writer);
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("max")) {
                        getMax(numList, writer);
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("avg")) {
                        getAverage(numList, writer);
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("p")) {
                        getPercentile(numList, line, writer);
                    } else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("sum")) {
                        getSum(numList, writer);
                    }
            }
            writer.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e + "File not found" );
            return; 
        }

    }
    //End main class
    
    // Class to split 
    public static int[] splitString(String line) {
        // trim the blank spaces on the line
        String shorterLine = line.substring(4).trim();
        
        //split the string 
        String[] list = shorterLine.split(",");
        int listLen = list.length;
        
        // Create an array and iterate through the numbers list
        int[] numList = new int[listLen];
        for (int i = 0; i != listLen; i++) {
            numList[i] = Integer.parseInt(list[i]);
        }
        return numList;
    }
    
    //Calculate the average number
    public static void getAverage(int[] numList, PrintWriter writer) {
        
        //calculate the sum of the array numbers
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + numList[i];
        }

        float average = sum / numList.length; 

        // Write average number to file 
        writer.format("The average of " + Arrays.toString(numList) + " is %.1f\n", average);

    }
    
    //calculate the sum 
    public static void getSum(int[] numList, PrintWriter writer) {
        // Iterate through the array 
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + numList[i];
        }

        // Write sum to file
        writer.println("The sum of " + Arrays.toString(numList) + " is " + sum);
    }
    
    // Get min number
    public static void getMin(int[] numList, PrintWriter writer) {
        int min = numList[0]; 
        for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++) {
            if (numList[i] < min) {
                min = numList[i];
            }
        }
        
        //Write to file
        writer.println("The min of " + Arrays.toString(numList) + " is " + min);

    }
    
    // Get Max number
    public static void getMax(int[] numList, PrintWriter writer) {
       
        int max = numList[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < numList.length; i++) {
            if (numList[i] > max) {
                max = numList[i];
            }
        }
        
      //Write to file
        writer.println("The max of " + Arrays.toString(numList) + " is " + max);
    }
    
    
    // Get percentile
    public static void getPercentile(int[] numList, String line, PrintWriter writer) {
        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(numList); 
     
        int parsedInteger = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(1, 3));
        
        // cast to float and divide by 100 to get the percentile
        float percentile = (float) parsedInteger / 100;
        
        // Calculate the index position for percentile
        // minus 1 to accommodate the fact that indexing is from 0
        int indexPercentile = (int) (numList.length * percentile) - 1; 

        //Write to file
        writer.format("The %.0f" + "th percentile of " + Arrays.toString(numList)
                + " is " + numList[indexPercentile] + "\n", percentile * 100);
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: The idea of all [format methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) is to have _one_ format string and variable arity arguments, such avoiding string concatenation: `writer.format("The average of %s is %.1f%n", Arrays.toString(numList), average);`. The same applies by replacing `println()` with `printf()`: `writer.printf("The sum of %s is %d%n", Arrays.toString(numList), sum);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) from an [`IntStream::summaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--).

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntSummaryStatistics statistics = intsFromStream(System.in)
        .summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("min: %d%nmax: %d%nsum: %d%navg: %.2f%n",
        statistics.getMin(),
        statistics.getMax(),
        statistics.getSum(),
        statistics.getAverage()
      );
  }
  private static IntStream intsFromStream(InputStream in) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
    Spliterator<String> spliterator = Spliterators.spliterator(scanner, Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL);
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false)
        .onClose(scanner::close)
        .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf);
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJrSwJBFP3ur7gEwho2kFEfNANJA8EHuBlBRNx0XMZ2ZpaZu5tS/nabfeUmuV/m7jnnvs7MGhO8WC8/9nshI20I1g5gQrPzTq2KxCTCfzFLhqNMqSh@D8UCFiFaC2MUCr5qAAVqCckdiRZLkI7zfDJCBS@vgCawjUwKMFTkx1Ki2fqp3roUm6fmYReEIvtgtPSztp6/tcQlE6qR5acfs8cVvEYnYwuxjolFrjmtvDMpVBvqy7qSuMkDl50HmAQuYK1VXZ01f6sfhmEBp7FbpHGSxM1p0q15muwl3GDAvXKpbP5daqYRCRIv3Uztynw4tmWoovhAle76C1SKG7DF2QXFP0vUc7rCpigU5AYgbW7zW7oDe8BcWkVhWYXyispNGGkVsHHv@e2pN5oPmtUMNp31B7NBH77/oJPpZDIfjYoZDKfYKMhX8OMofXTFU/MqDZuwwtDyyuVrdR9qy8tJ2u1F@lsRSIwetTPOeUQ8SBUJhjGfrgqTd/v9JbTgCq7h5gc)

Answer (score 0):

When reading and writing too and from files be sure to always close the resource when processing has finished. You can find multiple ways to do this. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for information on handling resources.

```
    File fileName = new File("input.txt");

    try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);){

        String input = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while(input != null) {
            //Do something... text file will be of type String.
            input = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("File not found " + fileName.getName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error processing file  " + fileName.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the condition in the while loop with: while(input.hasNext()) {  and check after if the input is an int